# Multiple bar plots in different figures but the same cell

Tags: python, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook, bar-chart

I've been trying to plot multiple figures in one cell in Python. The internet shows me only how to put multiple bars in one figure but I want to have multiple figures. Could not find out how to do it yet. This is the bar plot I have so far:

[image]

I wanna do the same for other columns and not only 'workclass'. So basically, the same plot. Any ideas how to do that? Thank you in advance!

Comment: This is a matplotlib question, not a matlab question, I assume. Please remove irrelevant tags. And what does " in one cell" mean? Is your question related to jupyter notebook? If so, this should be tagged as such. Please also read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a minimal, complete, and reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: If your current code works, why not just copy this entire code block, paste it at the end of cell, and change the column names?

Comment: @tdy lmao, works